# Need to know what is wrong here

Tags: struts2, tomcat7

I'm trying to learn the Struts2 framework.
I got the HelloWorld example form the site:

`www.vaannila.com/struts/struts-tutorial/struts-tutorial-using-eclipse-1.html

The highlighted code is shown as a warning:

`<%@taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %>`
**s:redirect forward="helloWorld"/>**

Th warning is given below:

Multiple annotations found at this line:
      - Unknown tag (bean:write).
      - Unknown tag (bean:write).

I get the same warning in my index.jsp file for the code:

and when i run the tomcat, I get the following in my console. I know my tomcat is running but how do i rectify this?

Jun 13, 2012 1:12:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init

```
**INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32;**

**Jun 13, 2012 1:12:28 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:StrutsExample1' did not find a matching property.**

Jun 13, 2012 1:12:28 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init

INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]

Jun 13, 2012 1:12:28 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init

INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]

Jun 13, 2012 1:12:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load

INFO: Initialization processed in 735 ms

Jun 13, 2012 1:12:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal

INFO: Starting service Catalina

Jun 13, 2012 1:12:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal

INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.27

Jun 13, 2012 1:12:31 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start

INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]

Jun 13, 2012 1:12:31 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start

INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]

Jun 13, 2012 1:12:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start

INFO: Server startup in 2586 ms
```

Comment: i am not able to understand your question properly as there seems no issue with S2 as per the console output.Additionally i suggets to download sample applications from officials S2 site

Comment: www.vaannila.com/struts/struts-tutorial/struts-tutorial-using-eclipse-1.html

Comment: aha..that's something related to S1 and i will not recommend to use it in S2, S2 provides equivalent tags for that and they are well integrated with them.

Comment: @VolkerK www.vaannila.com/struts/struts-tutorial/struts-tutorial-using-eclipse-1.html I download the example from the above site and followed the exact procedure. In the index.jsp and helloWorld.jsp files, I got an error message for the uri. So I changed the uri to "/struts-tags" in both the files.The i started to get errors for tags bean:write and bean:redirect and the warnings said "Unknown tags" I'm a newbie and need some help rectifying this problem. I use eclipse indigo and tomcat7

Comment: As said these tags are probable from S1 and now you are using S2, all you need to have following line in your jsp `<%@taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %>`

Comment: The same example when I directly run it on my web browser, It opens. But when I run it on eclipse. It show the above error message.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12595/discussion-between-user1448671-and-umesh-awasthi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<bean:write>` is struts 1.x you have to use `<s:property>` in struts 2.x.

See [s:property documentation](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/property.html)